# Showing that $|e^z - 1|\leq |z|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

Assume that $z$ is complex with $\text{Re}(z) \leq 0$.

> I'm trying to show that $$ |e^z - 1| \leq |z|$$
>
> and, similarly,
>
> $$ |e^z - z - 1| \leq |z|^2/2$$ holds.

The formulation of the exercise kind of hints to the series expansion of $e^z$, namely,

$$ e^z - 1 = z + \frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^3}{6} + o(z^4)$$

and similarly with $e^z - z - 1$. The $o(z)$ terms could probably be discarded applying triangle inequality, i.e.,

$$ |e^z - 1| = |z + o(z^2)| \leq |z|+|o(z^2)|$$

and

$$ \left|e^z -z -1 \right| = \left|\frac{z^2}{2} + o(z^3) \right| \leq \left|\frac{z^2}{2}\right|+|o(z^3)|$$

but I don't see why did we needed the negative real part here. Since $z$ is complex and I'm not used to that, I feel like I'm missing something (i.e., thinking about it, not entirely sure that $|z^2|=|z|^2$ in this case). Where am I wrong?

Comment: $|e^z-1|\leq |z|$ is obviously wrong for $z=3$ and you do not notice that you cannot just discard something of order $z^2$ or higher for numbers with positive real part. (Why?) I advise you write out what exactly happens with $|o(z^2)|$ for $z=3$ and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: @B.Swan OP mentioned $\Re(z)\leq 0$.

Comment: I know, and I told him why it is necessary, you cannot discard the terms $o(z^2), o(z^3)$ for numbers with positive *real* part. (Got that wrong in the first comment, will edit)

Comment: @B.Swan thanks, I'll try looking more into it.. Though, by a quick plugging-in of [both positive](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cz%5E2%2F2+%2B+z%5E3%2F3!+%2B+z%5E4%2F4!%7C++-++%7Cz%5E2%2F2+%2B+z%5E3%2F3!+%2B+z%5E4%2F4!+%2B+z%5E5%2F5!+%7C+at+z%3D(3+%2B+i*2)) case and [a negative one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cz%5E2%2F2+%2B+z%5E3%2F3!+%2B+z%5E4%2F4!%7C++-++%7Cz%5E2%2F2+%2B+z%5E3%2F3!+%2B+z%5E4%2F4!+%2B+z%5E5%2F5!+%7C+at+z%3D(-3+%2B+i*2)), due to negative differences it seems the sequence can be increasing for some $z^k$. So this does not come trivially to me.

Answer (score 3):

Let $z=a+bi$ with $a\le 0$. Then,
$$
|e^z-1|^2=e^{2a}-2e^a\cos b+1=(e^a-1)^2+2e^a(1-\cos b)
$$
$$
\le (e^a-1)^2+e^ab^2\le (e^a-1)^2+b^2
$$
(I used the inequalities $e^a\le 1$ for $a\le 0$ and $1-\cos b\le b^2/2$.

We end by observing that $(e^a-1)^2\le a^2$ for $a\le 0$.

Comment: This proofs resorts to real quantities but there probably are more elegant proofs using the power of complex analysis.

Answer (score 3):

@ Robert, you are right. You can proceed by induction. Assuming that $|e^z-\frac{z^n}{n!}-\dots -z-1|\le \frac{|z|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ , you can prove that it also holds with $n$ replaced by $n+1$ exactly in the same way you proceed to prove the inequality for $n=1$ from the case $n=0$.

This works just because the derivative of $e^z-\frac{z^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}-\dots -z-1$ is precisely $e^z-\frac{z^{n}}{n!}-\dots -z-1$. Using the inductive hypothesis you arrive at the upper bound  $\int\frac{|\gamma|^{n+1}(t)}{(n+1)!}|\gamma'(t)|dt$ which is equal to $\frac{|z|^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}$.

Comment: Or use the Taylor formula with integral remainder term (Schlömilch?). This gives directly the last expression, and can of course be proven using repeated partial integration as done here.

Comment: Very nice.  Glad you did this and saved me the trouble!

Answer (score 2):

Setting

$z = x + iy \tag 1$

with

$x \le 0, \tag 2$

we find that

$\vert e^z \vert = \vert e^{x + iy} \vert = \vert e^x \vert \vert e^{iy} \vert = e^x \le 1; \tag 3$

if $\gamma(t)$ is the  path joining $z$ and $w$ in the half-plane $\{u \in \Bbb C, \Re(u) \le 0 \}$ given by

$\gamma(t) = tw + (1 - t)z = z + t(w - z), \tag 4$

then since $e^z$ is the primitive of itself, that is, $(e^z)' = e^z$, we may write

$e^w - e^z = \displaystyle \int_0^1 (\exp(\gamma(t))' \; dt$
$= \displaystyle \int_0^1 \exp(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) \; dt = \int_0^1 \exp(\gamma(t)) (w - z) \; dt; \tag 5$

thus, by virtue of (3),

$\vert e^w - e^z \vert \le \displaystyle \int_0^1 \vert \exp(\gamma(t)) \vert \vert w - z \vert \; dt \le \vert w - z \vert; \tag 6$

set

$w = 0 \tag 7$

and find

$\vert e^z - 1 \vert = \vert e^z - e^0 \vert \le \vert z \vert, \tag 8$

which is the first desired inequality; next, note that

$(e^z - z - 1)' = e^z - 1; \tag 9$

$e^z - z - 1 = (e^z - z - 1) - (e^0 - 0 - 1) = \displaystyle \int_0^1 (\exp(\gamma(t) - 1)) \gamma'(t) \; dt, \tag{10}$

whence, using (8),

$\vert e^z - z - 1 \vert \le \displaystyle \int_0^1 \vert \exp(\gamma(t) - 1 \vert \vert \gamma'(t) \vert \; dt$
$\le \displaystyle \int_0^1 \vert \gamma(t) \vert \vert \gamma'(t) \vert \; dt = \int_0^1 \vert (1 - t)z \vert \vert z \vert \; dt = \vert z \vert^2 \int_0^1 (1 - t) \; dt  = \dfrac{\vert z \vert^2}{2}, \tag{11}$

the second inequality whose proof was sought.  $OE\Delta$.

***Nota Bene:***  I cannot help but wonder at this point if these results may not be extended to show that

$\left \vert e^z - \displaystyle \sum_0^n \dfrac{z^k}{k!} \right \vert \le \dfrac{\vert z \vert^{n + 1}}{(n + 1)!}, \tag{12}$

or some similar inequality; I suspect this is so but have not yet a complete proof, merely ideas; for example, we may be able to build (11) for larger $n$ by building upon established inequalities for lesser $n$, in a manner analogous to the way we have arrived at (11) based upon (8), etc. etc. etc. ***End of Note.***

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$|e^{z}-1|=|\int_{0}^{z}{e^{s}ds}|\leq \int_{0}^{z}{|e^{s}||ds|}= \int_{0}^{z}{e^{\Re(s)}|ds|}\leq \int_{0}^{z}|ds|=|z|$$

Since $\Re(s)\leq 0.$