Show that $|e^z-z-1|\leq\frac{|z|^2}{2}$ for $z$ in the left halfplane
I was wondering if somebody could tell me how to prove that $$|e^z-z-1|\leq\frac{|z|^2}{2}$$ based on the fact that $z$ is a complex number expressed as $z=a+ib$ with non-positive real part, i.e. $\operatorname{Re}(z) \leq 0$.
What I already know is that $|e^z-1|\leq|z|$ and that I can express the $|e^z-z-1|$ as:
\begin{align}\left|e^z-z-1\right| & = \left|\int_0^ze^x-1\ dx\right| \\ & =  \left|\int_0^ae^{-y+i\frac{b}{a}y}-1\ d\left(-y+i\frac{b}{a}y\right)\right| \\ & \leq  \left|-1+i\frac{b}{a}\right|\left(\int_0^a\left|e^{-y+i\frac{b}{a}y}\right|\ dy +\int_0^a 1 \ dy \right)\end{align}
What can I do with integral $\int_0^a1\ dy$ to attain the needed result?

Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080002/showing-that-ez-1-leq-z

\begin{align}|e^z-z-1| \le \frac{|z|^2}{2}\
|e^{a+ib}-a-ib-1| \le \frac{|a+ib|^2}{2}\
|e^{a}e^{ib}-a-ib-1| \le \frac{{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}^2}{2}\
|e^{a}\cos(b)+ie^{a}\sin(b)-a-ib-1| &\le \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\
|e^{a}\cos(b)-a-1+ie^{a}\sin(b)-ib| \le \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\
\sqrt{(e^{a}\cos(b)-a-1)^2+(e^{a}\sin(b)-b)^2} \le \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\end{align}
Square both sides, and use series for the trig

You can proceed as follows. Let $\theta = \arg z$. Then
\begin{align}|e^z-z-1| & =\left| \int_0^z(e^x-1) dx \right| \\& = \left| \int_0^{|z|} (e^{re^{i\theta}}-1) dr \right| \\ & \le \int_0^{|z|} |e^{re^{i\theta}}-1| dr \\ &\le \int_0^{|z|} r dr \\&= \frac{|z|^2}2.\end{align}
Here, I used $|e^z-1|\le |z|$ for $\Re(z)\le 0$ in the second inequality.

@Igalala please accept the answer if it’s helpful. Use comments only for clarifications.

We could generalize the nice method of Pranay using the formulas
$$\int_{0}^x \frac{(x-t)^n}{n!} \exp(t) dt = e^x - \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!} \\
\int_{0}^{|x|} \frac{(|x|-s)^n}{n!} ds = \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$
the first also holds for complex integration. Now for the first integral take as integration path a segment from $0$ to $x$. If $\mathcal{Re}\ x< 0$, then we'll have on that segment $|\exp(t)|\le 1$, and $|(x-t)| = |x|-|t| = |x|-s$.  Now use the second formula.
